# How should I specify path syntactically for sqlite3 in my .bashrc file?

Tags: sqlite, path, git-bash

The SQLite folder containing `sqlite3.exe` is in `C:\`.

I am trying to add a path to my `.bashrc` that will allow me to use the `sqlite3` command shell from `C:\Users\User`.

Again, structure is:

- `C:\Users\User` (using Git bash here) and
- `C:\sqlite\`

  - `sqlite3.exe`
  - `sqldiff.exe`
  - `sqlite3.def`
  - `sqlite3.dll`
  - `sqlite3_analyzer.exe`

I am attempting to use the `sqlite3` command shell in Git bash on windows 8.1.
This is what is in my .bashrc file per Janos recommendation:

```
alias 'subl="C://Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"'
PATH=/c/sqlite/:$PATH
```

Is there possibly anything else missing?

Comment: If `sqlite3.exe` is at `C:\sqlite\sqlite3.exe`, then add `/c/sqlite` to your `PATH`, for example: `PATH=/c/sqlite:$PATH`

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I tried that, and posted the picture in my edited question above. It didn't work. Is there possibly anything else that one should normally add to .bashrc to be able to use sqlite3? (Any other suggestions?)

Comment: I don't see any picture.  Can you *describe* what "didn't work".  (I'm actually not familiar with Git bash, but I think you should definitely use quotes in setting your path: `PATH="/c/sqlite:$PATH"`)

Comment: Varro, this PATH=/c/sqlite/:$PATH does not work. I also tried with quotes per your recommendation. And gitbash is very similar to linux cli. Is there supposed to be anything before you specify path (from your experience with linux)?

Comment: If you want good help, you *must* learn to describe your problem more precisely - saying something like "it doesn't work" is unlikely to elicit useful help.  A good start would be to list *exactly* what you did, and *exactly* what error messages you received.  (P.S. even if it *doesn't* fix your immediate problem, you definitely *should* use the quotes for PATH.)

Comment: Try this in a Git Bash shell: run `PATH=/c/sqlite/:$PATH` and then run `sqlite3`(or `sqlite3.exe`). This should work. And if it does, and you want to make it permanent, then your question becomes, in which file to add `PATH=/c/sqlite/:$PATH` to make it permanent.